# "Formal and informal writings differ in 1) a style 2) the style 3) style"

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I saw this in my representation after reading "The World as Will and Representation" by A. Schopenhauer:

> Formal and informal writings differ in **1) a style 2) the style 3) style.**

Which one is correct and why? I can't decide which one is correct as all of them seem correct to me.

Comment: Where did you see this question? It is very unusual English.

Comment: I saw it in my representation after reading "The World as Will and Representation" by A. Schopenhauer.  I don't know how unusual it is but the gist is clear.

Comment: **Correction**: Formal and informal writing differ in style. [What is a representation??]

Comment: Read the book..  Formal and informal writing differS in style

Answer (score 1):

When we use the preposition **in** followed by an single attribute noun like **style**, **colour** or **size**, we do not use a determiner, because the attribute is considered uncountable (so no **a**) and it's not considered specific (so no **the**).

> Have you noticed that his shoes are different in colour?
> The apples are all different in size.

Note that the word **writing** is normally considered uncountable. We only use the plural **[writings](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/writing)** when talking about the collected works of a specific person, for example "the writings of Karl Marx". If you were reading Haldane's translation of Schopenhauer, this was published in 1883 to 1886, and usage of the word **writings** may have changed since then.